# Delete duplicate elements from list by Identifier string (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have method to add elements to list
Here  is code

```
 public static List<InputDevice> GetAudioInputDevices()
    {
        var inputs = new List<InputDevice>();
        var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        var devicesAudio = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.All);
        foreach (var device in devicesAudio)
        {
            inputs.Add(new InputDevice()
            {
                Name = device.FriendlyName,
                Status = device.State.ToString(),
                DeviceId = device.ID,
                Identifier = device.FriendlyName.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper()
            });
        }


        return inputs;
    }
```

But sometimes I can have duplicates in `Identifier`

How I can return list without duplicates on return?

Comment: return  inputs.DistinctBy(x => x.Identifier ).ToList();

Comment: What is `DistinctBy`? I guess collections have only `Distinct` @JimmyN

Comment: sorry, I forgot, DistincyBy provided through https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ. Or you can do this: inputs.GroupBy(x => x.Identifier).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();

Comment: Is it possible that the duplicate Identifier has a different State (Active/NotPresent/Unplugged)? If you need only the Active ones, you can change the second parameter in "var devicesAudio = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active);" to return only the devices with State equal to DeviceState.Active

Comment: Is your requirement that `Identifier`  is the key field? The duplicate Identifier you mentioned here, then the Name and other fields are the same at this time? This is related to the data obtained by `devicesAudio`. If the same Identifier appears, which data do you want to choose to display? Maybe you should describe in detail.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to accomplish this, you could just skip the Adding of the item if it's already in the list:

```
        foreach (var device in devicesAudio)
        {
            string identifier = device.FriendlyName.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper();

            if (inputs.Any(input => input.Identifier == identifier))
                continue;

            inputs.Add(new InputDevice()
            {
                Name = device.FriendlyName,
                Status = device.State.ToString(),
                DeviceId = device.ID,
                Identifier = identifier
            });
        }
```

Or you could group the list by the identifier after the `foreach`, something like this:

```
inputs = inputs.GroupBy(i => i.Identifier)
    .Select(i => new InputDevice()
    {
        Identifier = i.Key,
        Status = i.First().Status,
        DeviceId = i.First().DeviceId,
        Name = i.First().Name
    }).ToList();
```

It really depends on what you need to do with the duplicated ones.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To make it faster you can use HashSet (complexity of Contains for HashSet is o(1)) and ask on each loop whether there already is a specific identifier in inputs List.

```
public static List<InputDevice> GetAudioInputDevices()
{
    var inputs = new List<InputDevice>();
    var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
    var devicesAudio = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.All);

    var usedIdentifiers = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var device in devicesAudio)
    {
        var identifier = device.FriendlyName.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper();
        if (usedIdentifiers.Contains(identifier))
            continue;

        inputs.Add(new InputDevice()
        {
            Name = device.FriendlyName,
            Status = device.State.ToString(),
            DeviceId = device.ID,
            Identifier = identifier
        });

        usedIdentifiers.Add(identifier);
    }


    return inputs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, I thing is this

```
    public static List<InputDevice> GetAudioInputDevices()
{
    var inputs = new List<InputDevice>();
    var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
    var devicesAudio = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.All);
    inputs = devicesAudio.GroupBy(d => d.FriendlyName.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper()).Select(g => g.First())
        .Select(d => new InputDevice()
        {
            Name = d.FriendlyName,
            Status = d.State.ToString(),
            DeviceId = d.ID,
            Identifier = d.FriendlyName.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper()
        }).ToList();
    return inputs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in website information about HashSet.